# String Arithmetic with vector and forward slash

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm running into a simple problem:

```
    string minEditOperations(vector<vector<int>> DPTable, string firstString, string secondString)
{
    //second string is what first string needs to be changed into, the DPTable function is    flipped
     int rowIterator = firstString.size() , columnIterator = secondString.size();

     string output;

while (rowIterator > 0 && columnIterator > 0)
{
    if (firstString[rowIterator - 1] == secondString[columnIterator - 1])
    {
            //Keep
            columnIterator--;
            rowIterator--;
            output = '^' + output;
    }
    else
    {
        //Calculate the different values
        int mincompare = min(DPTable[rowIterator - 1][columnIterator - 1], min(DPTable[rowIterator][columnIterator - 1], DPTable[rowIterator - 1][columnIterator]));

        if (DPTable[rowIterator - 1][columnIterator - 1] == mincompare)
        {
            output = "/" + firstString[rowIterator] + output;
        }
        else if (DPTable[rowIterator -1][columnIterator] == mincompare)
        {
            output = "-" + output;
        }
        else
        {
            //Right
            //Insert
            output = "+" + firstString[columnIterator] + output;
            columnIterator--;
        }

    }

}
return output;
}
```

I am attempting to "prepend" to a string, however whenever the code executes, the output string never changes.

```
 output = "+" + firstString[columnIterator] + output;
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you post more of your code please? It's hard to understand with just that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to arise from attempting to add strings to char values (since firstString[rowIterator] is a char).

Try something like this:

```
output = "/" + string(1, firstString[rowIterator]) + output;
```

That basically creates a string of length 1 from a char.